# Codificar e decoficar URL

Tags: php, criptografia

Tenho uma aplicação que preciso enviar links com informações do usuário, exemplo básico abaixo:

```
https://www.meusite.com.br/url?email=teste@email.com.br&token=token
```

Quero codificar a parte `email=teste@email.com.br&token=token` quando enviar o email  e decoficar quando receber. Vi que posso fazer este processo com base64, a dúvida é a seguinte, existe outro método sem ser a base64? Pois a base64 é mais fácil de ser lido por terceiros.

Comment: O mcrypt pode ser uma alternativa. Sugiro que dê uma olhada em:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mcrypt.php

Comment: Mcrypt infelizmente está deprecated e não é recomendado usar

Answer (score 1):

Usa-se o $_GET apenas para dados que não tem problema ser expostas na URL, como parâmetros de busca, onde o usuário pode copiar a URL e mandar para outra pessoa, que verá exatamente a mesma página que ela.

Quando estamos lidando com dados de usuário, o mais recomendado é usar $_POST com encriptação HTTPS. Encriptar e desencriptar strings no PHP é complicado, porquê você geralmente vai precisar de bibliotecas que não estão disponíveis em todas as hospedagens, como OpenSSL, etc. Veja: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262109/simplest-two-way-encryption-using-php

Segue um exemplo funcional com OpenSSL:

```
<?php

$chave = 'AlgumaStringAleatóriaSegura';
$texto = "minha mensagem";

function encriptar($texto, $chave)
{
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-128-CBC");
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
    $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($texto, $cipher, $chave, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $chave, $as_binary=true);
    return $ciphertext = base64_encode($iv.$hmac.$ciphertext_raw);
}

function desencriptar($textoCodificado, $chave)
{
    $c = base64_decode($textoCodificado);
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-128-CBC");
    $iv = substr($c, 0, $ivlen);
    $hmac = substr($c, $ivlen, $sha2len=32);
    $ciphertext_raw = substr($c, $ivlen+$sha2len);
    $texto_original = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext_raw, $cipher, $chave, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    $calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $chave, $as_binary=true);
    if (hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac)) {//PHP 5.6+ timing attack safe comparison
        return $texto_original."\n";
    }
}

// Texto encriptado
$textoEncriptado = encriptar($texto, $chave);
echo $textoEncriptado.'<br>';

// Texto desencriptado
$textoDesencriptado = desencriptar($textoEncriptado, $chave);
echo $textoDesencriptado.'<br>';
```